# Can't get a space between 2 inputs when stacked in mobile mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Below is a screenshot of my form, 
[image: mobile view]

and as you can see that there is no space between the State and County dropdown's. How can I have a space between those two when stacking? I guess I'll need more of a space between the two buttons as well.

I have tried adding col-xs-12 to the ddState, hoping that I could push it off and make it have a space between them, but to no avail.

My code is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <center><h1 style="font-weight:bold; color:#1d5f86">Create Alert</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="ddState" class="form-control max-size" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="ddCounty" class="form-control max-size" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="ddDepartment" class="form-control max-size"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="ddDistrict" class="form-control max-size"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End District -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" id="txtReporter" class="form-control" name="reporter" placeholder="Reporter" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
                            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="reporter"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End Reporting Party -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
                            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="address"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End Address -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="Cancel" class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-control" id="CancelFAR" style="background-color:#1D5F86; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                                <center><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">Cancel</a></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-control" id="SubmitFAR" style="background-color:#963146; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                                <center>Submit</center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the snippet and css

```css
.max-size {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <center>
              <h1 style="font-weight:bold; color:#1d5f86">Create Alert</h1>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="ddState" class="form-control max-size" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input id="ddCounty" class="form-control max-size topMargin" />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="ddDepartment" class="form-control max-size"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="ddDistrict" class="form-control max-size"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End District -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" id="txtReporter" class="form-control" name="reporter" placeholder="Reporter" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
              <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="reporter"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Reporting Party -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
              <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="address"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Address -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div id="Cancel" class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-control" id="CancelFAR" style="background-color:#1D5F86; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                <center><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/Home/Index ")" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">Cancel</a></center>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-control" id="SubmitFAR" style="background-color:#963146; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                <center>Submit</center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: The reason why the space isn't there is because you now have **2** inputs in one `.form-group`. You need to think that its **not** the `input`s themselves that have the `.margin-bottom:15px`, but the `.form-group`.

`form-group` class css

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The fix is as I said originally, add margin.

```
#ddState {
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```css
.form-group {
border:1px solid grey;}
.form-group.ad{border:1px solid grey;border-bottom-color:red}
    #ddState {
      margin-bottom:15px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <center>
              <h1 style="font-weight:bold; color:#1d5f86">Create Alert</h1>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group ad">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="ddState" value="I now have margin pushing outwards from the bottom onto *Foo*" class="form-control max-size" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input id="ddCounty" value="My name is Foo" class="form-control max-size topMargin" />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="ddDepartment" class="form-control max-size"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="ddDistrict" class="form-control max-size"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End District -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" id="txtReporter" class="form-control" name="reporter" placeholder="Reporter" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
              <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="reporter"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Reporting Party -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required validationMessage="Required" style="max-width:100%;" />
              <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="address"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Address -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div id="Cancel" class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-control" id="CancelFAR" style="background-color:#1D5F86; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                <center><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/Home/Index ")" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">Cancel</a></center>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-control" id="SubmitFAR" style="background-color:#963146; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                <center>Submit</center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect and compare the other selects, including their respective parent elements like the columns, rows. Do you notice anything different in the CSS between them and the state selector & parent elements? Do you now what is causing the gap naturally? And have you checked to see if what ever that is, is applied the same way to the state selector?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything popping out at me

Comment: There *has* to be something. Either that or your HTML is slightly broken somewhere

Comment: Post your CSS and create a snippet to reproduce the issue. That way I'll be able to dig into it myself to figure it out for you.